# Does anyone know how to activate the service SQL Server Agent?

Tags: sql-server

[image: Sql Server Agent]

I follow the steps of this site https://askgarth.com/blog/how-do-i-enable-sql-server-agent-service/ and this error pops-up.

Comment: Which version and edition of sql server are you running? The Express edition does not support the agent.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 and Microsoft SQL Tools 18

Comment: yes it's express, thank you so much

Comment: @AndreasRigas, if your need is only for development and testing (i.e. not production), consider using the free SQL Server Developer edition instead, which includes SQL Server Agent.

Comment: If you do switch to the developer edition, you need to design / code based on your production platform. The express edition does has other limitations.